# Sorting string which contains month and year - 'may - 2016'

Tags: php, arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

Description:

I have an assosiative array which stores the count of the article count for the specific month and year. It looks like this:

```
[
'april 2017' => 5,
'may 2017' => 5,
'december 2014' => 5,
'april 2016' => 5,
]
```

The problem:

This array have to be sorted from the newest to the oldest. I can't come up with the way of solving this sorting issue. I was thinking about using explode function but then the values are not ordered any more and makes no sense.Has anyone else had this problem ?

What would be the best approach/way of solving it ?

Comment: instead of building your associative array with keys like `may 2017`, use keys like `201705` and sort by key with ksort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions. Here are only two of them.

You can use [`uksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) function:

```
uksort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
});
```

Or you can use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php) function:

```
array_multisort(array_map('strtotime', array_keys($array)), $array);
```

Both of them use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert your string date representation to the timestamp and then compare timestamps.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3bada4e28f47c4e1bf65824acf9c33f40db5aee8).

**Pay attention** to that fact, that this only shows a concept. Meaning, that this code won't catch parsing errors and [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can return `false` if your date keys are invalid. In such case, the code won't fail, but the results will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime()` on your date strings like `'april 2017'` to get a comparable data.

Once you have this, just find a sorting algorithm which match your needs : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm.
This choice will depend on the way data are stored in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$array = [
'april 2017' => 5,
'may 2017' => 6,
'december 2014' => 3,
'april 2016' => 4,
];

function order_date($a1,$b1) {
    $format = 'M Y';
    $a = strtotime(date_format(DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $a1), 'Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $b = strtotime(date_format(DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $b1), 'Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    if ($a == $b)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ($a > $b)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}

uksort($array, "order_date");

print_r($array);
```